# OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() throws an exception?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, exception, .net-4.0

I am trying to show a dialog from one of my WPF view model commands however when i call `ShowDialog()` it throws a `System.ArgumentException`, I was wondering if anyone could give me a hint as to why?

Here is my code:

```
Public ReadOnly Property OpenParser As ICommand
    Get
        Return New RelayCommand(Sub(param As Object) OpenParserExecute(DirectCast(param, Frame)))
    End Get
End Property

Public Sub OpenParserExecute(ByVal mFrame As Frame)
    SaveParserExecute()
    Dim mOpenDialog As OpenFileDialog = OpenDialog
    If mOpenDialog.ShowDialog() Then ' Lines the throws the exception
        CurrentParser = New ParserEditorModel(mOpenDialog.FileName)
        mFrame.Navigate(New ParserEditor(CurrentParser))
    End If
End Sub
```

StackTrace as requested:

```
at MS.Internal.Interop.HRESULT.ThrowIfFailed(String message)
at MS.Internal.AppModel.ShellUtil.GetShellItemForPath(String path)
at Microsoft.Win32.FileDialog.PrepareVistaDialog(IFileDialog dialog)
at Microsoft.Win32.FileDialog.RunVistaDialog(IntPtr hwndOwner)
at Microsoft.Win32.FileDialog.RunDialog(IntPtr hwndOwner)
at Microsoft.Win32.CommonDialog.ShowDialog()
at WinTransform.GUI.MainWindowModel.OpenParserExecute(Frame mFrame) in C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\MEDLI\branches\WinTransform\GUI\ViewModels\MainWindowModel.vb:line 38
```

Comment: There's something wrong with your OpenDialog object.  Hard to guess what it might be unless you post the exception's StackTrace.

Comment: There's something wrong with the OpenDialog.InitialDirectory property.

Comment: Yeah there was, thanks for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `ShowDialog()` itself returns a `Nullable(Of Boolean)` and your `If` statement is expecting a non-Nullable `Boolean`.

You'll have to cast the dialog's return value to a `Boolean` and if it's `True` retreive the selected file through your dialog's `Filename` property.

[Example](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/dbeniwal321/OpenFileDialogwpf08162009233449PM/OpenFileDialogwpf.aspx).